# Referenced security token could not be retrieved (Reference "Issuer/Serial data element missing")

Tags: web-services, spring-security, weblogic

I am facing issue while integrating a spring base web service framework. A  stand alone instance of the framework works perfectly fine.But after integrating with web-logic it gives the following exception. My assumption  is conflicting  jars while parsing the security header of the response.

```
     Could not validate request: Referenced security token could not be retrieved 
    (Reference "Issuer/Serial data element missing"); nested exception is: 
        org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.XMLSecurityException: 
Cannot create a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:X509IssuerSerial from a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:X509IssuerSerial element; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Referenced security token could not be retrieved (Reference "Issuer/Serial data element missing");
```

ultimately resulting in

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault").
```

Comment: any help will be helpfull

Comment: please let me know...if  detail log tracer will be helpful..not getting any clue...